# Building $or query using dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

I'm struggling here. I'm new to doing anything even remotely complex in mongo.

Given following documents in mongo:

```
{ Id = 1, SharedId = "K1", Tag = "V1" }
{ Id = 2, SharedId = "K1", Tag = "V2" }
{ Id = 3, SharedId = "K1", Tag = "V3" }
{ Id = 4, SharedId = "K2", Tag = "V1" }
{ Id = 5, SharedId = "K2", Tag = "V2" }
{ Id = 6, SharedId = "K2", Tag = "V3" }
```

I have a method `GetRecords(Dictionary<string, List<string>> docs)` for which the key is `SharedId` and the List contains a list of `Tags`. Example:

```
[
    { "K1", [ "V1", , "V3" ] },
    { "K2", [ "V2", "V3" ] }
]
```

I would like to extract the following records:

```
1, 3, 5, 6
```

My current method looks like this.

```
GetRecords(Dictionary<string, List<string>> docs)
{
    var filter = Builders<Dto>.Filter.Where(d =>
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.SharedId) &&
        docs.Keys.Contains(d.SharedId))
}
```

Attempting to get any further than that with what I am using throws many errors from mongo, usually `NotSupported` etc. Something like `docs[d.SharedId].Any(i => docs.Contains(i))` makes mongodriver quite upset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear from the notation in your question if you mean a structure like this ( showing serialized JSON form ):

```
{ "K1": [ "V1", "V3" ], "K2": [ "V2", "V3" ] }
```

Or like this:

```
[
  { "K1": [ "V1", "V3" ] },
  { "K2": [ "V2", "V3" ] }
]
```

In either way, you're basically either iterating key/value pairs of a singular dictionary or pretty much the same for a "list of dictionary".

The end result means constructing a query like this from either initial form:

```
      {
        "$or" : [
            {
              "SharedId" : "K1",
              "Tag" : { "$in" : [ "V1", "V3" ] }
            },
            {
              "SharedId" : "K2",
              "Tag" : { "$in" : [ "V2", "V3" ] }
            }
        ]
      }
```

And the basic way to do that is to use a `foreach` to iterate and make a list of `FilterDefinition` which you then supply to `Builders<T>.Filter.Or`

An example listing with have code like this:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
      var client = new MongoClient();
      var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
      var entities = db.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");

      try
      {
        /*
         * Meaning a serialized structure like:
         * { "K1": [ "V1", "V2" ], "K2": [ "V2", "V3" ] } 
         */
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
          { "K1", new List<string> { "V1", "V3" } },
          { "K2", new List<string> { "V2", "V3" } }
        };

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        /*
         *  Meaning a serialized structure like:
         *  [
         *    { "K1": [ "V1", "V2" ] },
         *    { "K2": [ "V2", "V3" ] }
         *  ]
         */
        List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> alt = new List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>
        {
          {  new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { { "K1", new List<string> {  "V1", "V3" } } } },
          {  new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { { "K2", new List<string> {  "V2", "V3" } } } },
        };

        string output2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alt);
        Console.WriteLine(output2);

        // Build query from 'dict' form
        List<FilterDefinition<Entity>> orConditions = new List<FilterDefinition<Entity>>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in dict)
        {
          orConditions.Add(
            Builders<Entity>.Filter.Eq(p => p.SharedId, entry.Key) &
            Builders<Entity>.Filter.Where(p => entry.Value.Contains(p.Tag))
          );
        };
        var query1 = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Or(orConditions);
        /*
         * Builds -
          {
            "$or" : [
                {
                  "SharedId" : "K1",
                  "Tag" : { "$in" : [ "V1", "V3" ] }
                },
                {
                  "SharedId" : "K2",
                  "Tag" : { "$in" : [ "V2", "V3" ] }
                }
            ]
          }
        */
        Console.WriteLine("Output 1");
        var cursor1 = await entities.Find(query1).ToListAsync();
        foreach (var doc in cursor1)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(doc.ToBsonDocument());
        }

        // Build the query from 'alt' form
        orConditions = new List<FilterDefinition<Entity>>(); // clear the list

        foreach(var item in alt)
        {
          foreach(KeyValuePair<string,List<string>> entry in item)
          {
            orConditions.Add(
              Builders<Entity>.Filter.Eq(p => p.SharedId, entry.Key) &
              Builders<Entity>.Filter.Where(p => entry.Value.Contains(p.Tag))
            );
          }
        }

        var query2 = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Or(orConditions);

        /* Serializes just the same */
        Console.WriteLine("Output 2");
        var cursor2 = await entities.Find(query2).ToListAsync();
        foreach (var doc in cursor2)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(doc.ToBsonDocument());
        }


      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }

    }
  }

  public class Entity
  {
    public int id;
    public string SharedId { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
  }
}
```

That shows the conversion from either data structure form to the same query, which returns the expected documents:

```
{"K1":["V1","V3"],"K2":["V2","V3"]}
[{"K1":["V1","V3"]},{"K2":["V2","V3"]}]
Output 1
{ "_id" : 1, "SharedId" : "K1", "Tag" : "V1" }
{ "_id" : 3, "SharedId" : "K1", "Tag" : "V3" }
{ "_id" : 5, "SharedId" : "K2", "Tag" : "V2" }
{ "_id" : 6, "SharedId" : "K2", "Tag" : "V3" }
Output 2
{ "_id" : 1, "SharedId" : "K1", "Tag" : "V1" }
{ "_id" : 3, "SharedId" : "K1", "Tag" : "V3" }
{ "_id" : 5, "SharedId" : "K2", "Tag" : "V2" }
{ "_id" : 6, "SharedId" : "K2", "Tag" : "V3" }
```

Comment: The alt form isn't something I need and sorry for making it unclear. What if I wanted to return the opposite? So instead of returning `1, 3, 5 and 6` I wanted a query that would return what isn't matched so documents `2 and 4`? Is it simply `Where(p => !entry.Value.Contains(p.Tag))`?